# SSRS: Placeholder not showing value defined by a dataset value (query type) obtained by user parameter

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, visual-studio-2019, placeholder

Creating a report on ***SSRS*** on ***Visual Studio 2019***, when previewing the report, I need to assign to a textbox (placeholder) a value obtained by a dropdown filter that I created with a query result.

Expression for the placeholder: `=First(Fields!ProjectName.Value, "ProjectNames")`

Dataset name: `ProjectNames`

Value name: `ProjectName`

This value name is dynamic defined in a dropdown filter by the user, but the selected value (ProjectName) is not being shown on the report textbox, as a matter of fact, it does not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dataset called `ProjectNames` and that supplies values to a parameter called `ProjectID` and you want to show the selected value in the report?

As the dataset `ProjectNames` includes both ProjectID and ProjectName columns I am assuming that in oyur parameter properties you have the Parameter 'Value' set to `ProjectID` and the 'Label' set to `ProjectName`

If so then you can simply set the textbox value expression to this

```
=Parameters!ProjectID.Label
```

or if the parameter is a multi-value parameter and you always want the first entry  (I find this unlikely) then

```
=Parameters!ProjectID.Label(0)
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your response! Here is the thing: I don't have a parameter ProjectName, I am using a parameter ProjectID (besides other ones that filter according to dates), that parameter is extracted from a query (dataset ProjectNames that includes the fields: ProjectName and ProjectID). The issue is that, once that I preview the report, what I am looking for is to show in a textbox (I found that I am supposed to use a Placeholder) is the name of the project that the user selects but I cannot do that, I just can show the ID of the project in the textbox.

Comment: Most of my answer still applies but I've updated it to reflect the new info.